# pass function as state through Link in react router v1.0

Tags: reactjs, react-router

Is possible to pass a function as state with Link?

```
const userAndEvalSubmissions = {
  'evalSubmissions': evalSubmissions,
  'user': this.props.user,
  'changeScore': this.changeScore // a method in component
  }

<Link
  className="btn btn-success"
  to={}
  state={userAndEvalSubmissions}>
  Scores
</Link>
```

I tried passing it along with other objects but only objects got through. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, this goes into the location state and thus must be serializable. Per [MDN's History API docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/History_API):

> The state object is a JavaScript object which is associated with the new history entry created by `pushState()`. ... The state object can be anything that can be serialized.

Comment: i see. thanks. im using react-router `Link` to transit and pass state to the next component in another file. if i cant pass component method through `Link`, is there any other ways to achieve this?

Comment: @shangyeshen You'll need to find some other place to store the function.